# Retrieve selected tags from the Jquery Tag it! plugin on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, tag-it

I've found this nice jquery plugin tag it! http://levycarneiro.com/2010/03/tag-it-tag-suggestions-editor-and-autocomplete-in-a-jquery-ui-plugin/ and want to implement it into an ASP.Net application.

Upon inspecting the source code, I found out, that the plugin adds additional li items (with remove links and so on) into an ul.

How can I retrieve the selected tags upon a PostBack?

Comment: could you possibly explain why should there be a postback? can you not use ajax pagemethod or something like that?

Comment: I have a form where I have certain textboxes, dropdown lists et cetera and add a record in my database based on that input. A want to add a tag functionality to the  record. So I can only save the selected values after I inserted the record. But I want to do it with one submit

Comment: what would prevent you from saving tags on client click with page method and then proceeding with a return true onto postback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@citronas, i used this jQuery tag plugin: [jQuery Tagit](http://jquery.webspirited.com/2011/02/jquery-tagit-a-jquery-tagging-plugin/)

I modified it as follows to both load the plugin with tags from the server side and retrieve selected tags on the server side.

```
    ...<script>
    $(function () {

        var availableTags = $("#<%= hdnDBTags.ClientID %>").val().split(',');

        $('#demo1').tagit({ tagSource: availableTags, select: true });

        $("#<%= btnGetTags.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            getTagsString($('#demo1').tagit('tags'))
        });

        function getTagsString(tags) {
            var string = "";

            for (var i in tags) {
                string += tags[i] + ",";
            }

            $("#<%= hdnSelectedTags.ClientID %>").val(string);
        }
    });
</script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnDBTags" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSelectedTags" runat="server" />
<h1>
    Your Profile</h1>
<p>
    <ul id="demo1" name="nameOfSelect">
    </ul>
    <asp:Button ID="btnGetTags" runat="server" Text="Get Tags" OnClick="btnGetTags_Click" />
</p>
```

And in the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hdnDBTags.Value = "real_estate,mortgage_lending";
}

protected void btnGetTags_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string test = hdnSelectedTags.Value;

    IList<string> array = test.Split(',').ToList();

    array.Remove("");
}
```

Hope this helps...

D